# Show roles dropdown list in registration form FOSUser

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

Hi everyone and thank you for your time
I'm under `Symfony 3.0.2` and i'm using `FOSUserBundle 2.0`. The problem is when i want to load the registration page it shows only the `Email`, `password`, and `username`. However i would like to show more field in the form, especially ROLES that i'll fill manually 
If someone has an idea
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType.php

you can add fields :(example)

```
$builder

            ->add('name','text', array(
                'label' => 'Nom',
                'attr'  => array( 'placeholder' => 'Nom',  )))
```

Comment: Thank you, for your response. but i would like to know how to add ROLES which containes ROLE_MEMBER, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN AND ROLE_MODERATOR

Comment: ->add('roles','collection',array('type'  =>  'choice','options' =>array(

                'choices' => array('ROLE_MEMBER' => 'ROLE_MEMBER', 'ROLE_MODERATOR' => 'ROLE_MODERATOR','ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'))))

Comment: I tried your solution but i got this error : Could not load type "collection"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Comment: add this use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

Comment: Added it but always the same problem CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Could not load type "collection"" at /Users/benjy/Sites/acm_symfo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php line 87

Comment: i tried this ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'=> ['Member' => 0, 'Association' => 1,'Manager' => 2, 'Admin' => 3] ]) and it works, however in value of option list i want to have a string value not a number, is there any comment about this ?